# Is there a single verbal phrase that means 'attacking with a group of people'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single phrasal verb that indicates the act of attacking or assaulting by a group of people. Something that might replace **group-attacked** in

> The messenger was **group-attacked** by road bandits.

Comment: One might say "mobbed", except that the term does not *necessarily* imply violence.

Answer (score 1):

I think an appropriate word for your specific example might be **ambushed** as in:

> The messenger was **ambushed** by road bandits

Or, to more explicitly suggest large numbers (inspired by Hot Licks' comment):

> The messenger was ambushed by a mob of road bandits

Ambush means a concealed or surprise attack ([TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ambush)), although it does not always imply large numbers (you can be ambushed by only one person). You could use a different noun to express the large numbers, for example [**swarm**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Swarm) or mob or crowd or gang.

Answer (score 0):

[**gang up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gang%20up)

> **to join together as a group especially to attack, oppose, or criticize**

The phrase can be applied to your example in a few ways:

> *The messenger was **ganged up on** by road bandits.* (very rarely used, avoid if possible)

or

> *Road bandits **ganged up on** the messenger and assaulted him/her.*

Do note that this word is fairly informal.